# Axios api call returns not found error in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm requesting post axios call with 2 parameters.

```
export const getUser = (page,Type) => {
   axios.post(APIURL.apiURL, 
        {
        page: page,
        auth: Type
    }, {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

I tried both version but returns Http request blocked by CORS  Policy.Is there any other way to send body in axios call.

Comment: you should add Access-Control-Allow-Origin meta

Comment: where to add it.

Comment: check it I have edited your question

Comment: @DostonbekOripjonov tried but no use

Comment: CORS should be added to server. If you are using node then use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to request headers:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

If not, then you need to proxy the request somehow. The easiest way to do it in this scenario is to use the 'http-proxy-middleware' npm package

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow origin from back-end side. It's not an issue of front-end code.

You have to add below lines in your API middleware at backend.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE'
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': ' true'
```